# Flutter - Instance of 'Future<double>' instead number

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future

I'm on Flutter project and from the code  below I retrieved the distance from the user's position and a fixed place.

But when I compile the code, the app shows `Instance of 'Future<double>'` instead of distance but with print my console shows the distance:

```
class ProductHorizontalListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductHorizontalListItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.coreTagKey,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final Function? onTap;
  final String coreTagKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('***Tag*** $coreTagKey${PsConst.HERO_TAG__IMAGE}');
    final PsValueHolder valueHolder =
    Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

Future<double> getCurrentLocation() async {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
      double lat = position.latitude;
      double long = position.longitude;
      final double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
        double.parse(position.latitude.toString()),
        double.parse(position.longitude.toString()),
        double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lat.toString()),
        double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lng.toString()),
      );
        print(distanceInMeters);
        return await distanceInMeters;

    }

    final Future<void> position = getCurrentLocation();

    return InkWell(
        onTap: onTap as void Function()?,
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: PsDimens.space4, right: PsDimens.space4,
                bottom: PsDimens.space12),
            child: Text(
                '${position}' '${product.itemLocation!.name}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3
                )))

        );
  }
}
```

I cannot understand what is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are a couple of things.

1. `distanceInMeters` is not a `Future`, so instead of using the `await` keyword before returning, you should return the double value from `getCurrentLocation` like this:

```
return Future.value(distanceInMeters);
```

2. This code: `final Future<void> position = getCurrentLocation();` is problematic, because `getCurrentLocation()` has a type of `Future<double>`. Normally you should use it like below, but this is a `build` function, where you are not allowed to use `await`, you can't mark the `build` function as `async`.

```
final position = await getCurrentLocation();
```

3. To solve your issue you could use a `FutureBuilder`, which will wait for the result of `getCurrentLocation()` and build the widget once the future is completed. Please refer to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for details (especially on how to create the future properly), but basically something like this:

```
return FutureBuilder<double>(
  future: getCurrentLocation(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return InkWell(...); // use `snapshot.data` to get the double value 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your indication but now I have "AsyncSnapshot<double>" instead of my value :(

Comment: Sorry! It works! I forget to add toString()

Comment: can you reply also here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615153/flutter-futurebuilder-sometimes-gives-me-null-distance-on-list-of-item

It's the evolution of this answer

Comment: Make sure that you extract the value as `snapshot.data`, `AsyncSnapshot<double>` could mean that you use only `snapshot`. I will look at the other question of you.